# RadioButton as ItemRenderer allowing more than 1 selection in mx Datagrid

Tags: flex4, radio-button, itemrenderer

I need help with radionbuttons as itemRenderer in an mx datagrid. I want to be table to select only 1 radiobutton at a given time but my datagrid is allowing to selected more than 1 radio. i dont want this behaviour.

```
I have also included a groupName to the radioButtons in the itemRenderer but still it doe4s not work.

Please have a look at my codes below and help me with this.


<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" showHeaders="false" headerHeight="0"
                                 fontSize="9" x="20" y="20" width="217" height="30">
                        <mx:columns>
                            <mx:DataGridColumn width="20" headerText="isDefault" dataField="@IS_DEFAULT">
                                <mx:itemRenderer>
                                    <fx:Component>
                                        <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="left">
                                            <s:RadioButton selected="@{data.isDefault}" group="{outerDocument.rbg1}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
                                        </mx:HBox>
                                    </fx:Component>
                                </mx:itemRenderer>
                            </mx:DataGridColumn>    
                        </mx:columns>
                    </mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure that rbg1 is a public not private var. Additionally, I never use outerDocument. I always stick with parentApplication. Some folks nay-say it but it has never failed me. Give that a shot.